# Why does MySQL autoincrement increase on failed inserts?

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

A co-worker just made me aware of a very strange MySQL behavior.

Assuming you have a table with an auto_increment field and another field that is set to unique (e.g. a username-field). When trying to insert a row with a username thats already in the table the insert fails, as expected. Yet the auto_increment value is increased as can be seen when you insert a valid new entry after several failed attempts.

For example, when our last entry looks like this...

```
ID: 10
Username: myname
```

...and we try five new entries with the same username value on our next insert we will have created a new row like so:

```
ID: 16
Username: mynewname
```

While this is not a big problem in itself it seems like a very silly attack vector to kill a table by flooding it with failed insert requests, as the MySQL Reference Manual states:

> "The behavior of the auto-increment mechanism is not defined if [...] the value becomes bigger than the maximum integer that can be stored in the specified integer type."

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Your attack vector seems a non issue. If you could flood it with failed insert requests couldn't you equally flood it with non failed requests?

Comment: @martin smith: While thats true I think a sudden surge of new users would be more obvious than a silent increase in the auto_increment that might very well fall by the wayside if not checked for.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`InnoDB` is a transactional engine.

This means that in the following scenario:

1. `Session A` inserts record `1`
2. `Session B` inserts record `2`
3. `Session A` rolls back

, there is either a possibility of a gap or `session B` would lock until the `session A` committed or rolled back.

`InnoDB` designers (as most of the other transactional engine designers) chose to allow gaps.

From the [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

> When accessing the auto-increment counter, `InnoDB` uses a special table-level `AUTO-INC` lock that it keeps to the end of the current `SQL` statement, not to the end of the transaction. The special lock release strategy was introduced to improve concurrency for inserts into a table containing an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column
>
> …
>
> `InnoDB` uses the in-memory auto-increment counter as long as the server runs. When the server is stopped and restarted, `InnoDB` reinitializes the counter for each table for the first `INSERT` to the table, as described earlier.

If you are afraid of the `id` column wrapping around, make it `BIGINT` (8-byte long).

Comment: Your answer helped me with my own problem a lot. Thank you. is there a way to bypass this behaviour of InnoDB regarding autoincrement?

Comment: @Ankit: please post it as another question and put a link here.

Comment: As you requested: [Other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mysql+bigint)

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing the exact internals, I would say yes, the auto-increment SHOULD allow for skipped values do to failure inserts.  Lets say you are doing a banking transaction, or other where the entire transaction and multiple records go as an all-or-nothing.  If you try your insert, get an ID, then stamp all subsequent details with that transaction ID and insert the detail records, you need to ensure your qualified uniqueness.  If you have multiple people slamming the database, they too will need to ensure they get their own transaction ID as to not conflict with yours when their transaction gets committed.  If something fails on the first transaction, no harm done, and no dangling elements downstream.

Comment: its the use of this skkiping nature of auto increment but i want to know is this any way to stop this skkiping

Comment: @Ankit, no, you can't stop the skipping.  The file header which keeps track of the last ID that was assigned always increments.  If there's a problem, and 10 people are entering transactions and 3 abort, you'll never want to backfill such aborted transaction just to use an ID.

Answer (score 4):

Old post, 
but this may help people, 
You may have to set [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode) to **0 or 2**.

System variables that take a numeric value can be specified as `--var_name=value` on the command line or as `var_name=value` in option files.

**Command-Line parameter format:**

```
--innodb-autoinc-lock-mode=0
```

**OR**
Open your mysql.ini and add following line :

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

Answer (score -3):

I know that this is an old article but since I also couldn't find the right answer, I actually  found a way to do this. You have to wrap your query within an if statement. Its usually insert query or insert and on duplicate querys that mess up the organized auto increment order so for regular inserts use:

```
$check_email_address = //select query here\\

if ( $check_email_address == false ) {
    your query inside of here
}
```

and instead of ***INSERT AND ON DUPLICATE*** use a ***UPDATE SET WHERE QUERY*** in or outside an if statement doesn't matter and a ***REPLACE INTO QUERY*** also does seem to work

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer as it isn't applicable at all. Yes, you can check if a record exists before trying the insert, but that is completely beside the point.