# Prevent auto increment on MySQL duplicate insert

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, innodb, auto-increment

Using MySQL 5.1.49, I'm trying to implement a tagging system
the problem I have is with a table with two columns: `id(autoincrement)`, `tag(unique varchar)` *(InnoDB)*

When using query, `INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename SET tag="whatever"`, the auto increment `id` value increases even if the insert was ignored.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but I expect a lot of possible attempts to insert duplicates for this particular table which means that my next value for `id` field of a new row will be jumping way too much.

For example I'll end up with a table with say 3 rows but bad `id`'s

```
1   | test
8   | testtext
678 | testtextt
```

Also, if I don't do `INSERT IGNORE` and just do regular `INSERT INTO` and handle the error, the auto increment field still increases so the next true insert is still a wrong auto increment.

Is there a way to stop auto increment if there's an `INSERT` duplicate row attempt?

As I understand for MySQL 4.1, this value wouldn't increment, but last thing I want to do is end up either doing a lot of `SELECT` statements in advance to check if the tags exist, or worse yet, downgrade my MySQL version.

Comment: Are you using InnoDB? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787910/why-does-mysql-autoincrement-increase-on-failed-inserts

Comment: ah yes. i just did a quick edit. i'll check out the link tnx

Comment: just a follow up on that link. sadly it doesn't really solve the problem but rather attempts a bigint for the id field to avoid having the table blow up. Thanks though

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could modify your INSERT to be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (tag)
SELECT $tag
FROM tablename
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT tag
    FROM tablename
    WHERE tag = $tag
)
LIMIT 1
```

Where `$tag` is the tag (properly quoted or as a placeholder of course) that you want to add if it isn't already there. This approach won't even trigger an INSERT (and the subsequent autoincrement wastage) if the tag is already there. You could probably come up with nicer SQL than that but the above should do the trick.

If your table is properly indexed then the extra SELECT for the existence check will be fast and the database is going to have to perform that check anyway.

This approach won't work for the first tag though. You could seed your tag table with a tag that you think will always end up being used or you could do a separate check for an empty table.

Comment: was trying to avoid that, but i have an idea.

execute the following sql statement after each insert. it resets the autoincrement for id to the last one actually used.

    ALTER TABLE tags AUTO_INCREMENT = 1


possible problems with this. it seems to cause an update for all rows but ids aren't changed. it returns rows affected xx that is the # of records in the table.

aside from this i can see having a dummy table store the number of tags and the counter will be updated when new tags are added. So instead of using autoincrement , i'll be managing my own ids.

Comment: @robert: You will run into concurrency issues if you try to manage your own IDs. Or you'll have to do a bunch of table locking to simulate the restricted access to auto-incrementing does by itself. Why are you trying to avoid checking for duplicates before the INSERT? Have you checked that there is a real performance hit?

Comment: no i suppose nothing too serious , it just seemed like bad practice. Speaking of which, the execution time for ALTER TABLE tags AUTO_INCREMENT = 1  is worse.

Comment: Great solution, had some trouble getting it to insert a row initially. I found that if the table you are selecting from is empty, the insert will not happen.

Comment: @Jbrown: You're right, an empty table can be a problem. I think the easiest thing to do is to manually add a tag to the table when you create it, something that you know will get used. Usually I just go the "add a unique constraint, blindly insert tags, catch/ignore the expected errors" route and not worry about the auto-increment values.

Comment: @muistooshort: Good tip. But why do you say it will not insert into an empty table? I tried it and it works. (Hit this post while I was looking for the same query).

Comment: @Ethan: The problem is the first `from tablename`. If the table is empty then that gives you "nonexistent" rather than an empty set. There could be MySQL version issues involved, I'm checking with 5.5.

Comment: @muistooshort: Got your point. I have tried this with 5.5, Percona build and didn't face it.

Comment: the inserts were failing for me if the table was empty, i slightly modified the insert query and posted it as an answer below, give it a try if you experience the failure on an empty table situation

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` is required because the subquery generates a temporary table that contains as many rows as the original table itself. Isn't this problematic, or at least bad practice? For example, the temporary table will contain millions of rows if the original table contains millions of rows.

Comment: @helloworld Does MySQL actually generate a temp table or is it smart enough to know what "exists" means?

Comment: Why would `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` have any impact on whether a temporary table is created?

Comment: @helloworld Depends on how smart the query optimizer is. Why go to the effort of generating a temporary table when all you really care about is whether or not something would be in it?

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation, the `LIMIT 1` is applied to the subquery (`SELECT` statement), not to the outer query (`INSERT` statement). Therefore there is no need to add an additional `LIMIT 1` to the subquery since it is already there.

Answer (score 16):

I just found this gem...

http://www.timrosenblatt.com/blog/2008/03/21/insert-where-not-exists/

```
INSERT INTO [table name] SELECT '[value1]', '[value2]' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT [column1] FROM [same table name]
    WHERE [column1]='[value1]'
    AND [column2]='[value2]' LIMIT 1
)
```

If affectedRows = 1 then it inserted; otherwise if affectedRows = 0 there was a duplicate.

Comment: Nice. Basically the same as Landon's solution, but more elegant by using the DUAL fake table.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it works even if table is empty. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

The MySQL documentation for v 5.5 says:

```
"If you use INSERT IGNORE and the row is ignored, the AUTO_INCREMENT counter 
is **not** incremented and LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0, 
which reflects that no row was inserted."
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Since version 5.1 InnoDB has configurable Auto-Increment Locking. See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-inc...

Workaround: use option innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0 (traditional).

Comment: Interestingly enough, with non-traditional, it still increments for me using `INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for MySQL 5.5.41

Comment: If you use INSERT IGNORE and the row is ignored, the LAST_INSERT_ID() remains unchanged from the current value (or 0 is returned if the connection has not yet performed a successful INSERT)

it will return 0 if the action doesn't preformed

Answer (score 14):

I found mu is too short's answer helpful, but limiting because it doesn't do inserts on an empty table. I found a simple modification did the trick:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (tag)
SELECT $tag
FROM (select 1) as a     #this line is different from the other answer
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT tag
    FROM tablename
    WHERE tag = $tag
)
LIMIT 1
```

Replacing the table in the from clause with a "fake" table `(select 1) as a` allowed that part to return a record which allowed the insert to take place. I'm running mysql 5.5.37.  Thanks mu for getting me most of the way there ....

Comment: @langla: NO, it doesnt. It was my fault: "tag" is the column name and "$tag" the column value :-)

Comment: Very nice, thanks for that. Couldn't figure out for a while why my code isn't working with empty tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can always add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` [Read here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (not exactly, but solves your problem it seems).

From the comments, by @ravi

> Whether the increment occurs or not depends on the
>   innodb_autoinc_lock_mode setting. If set to a non-zero value, the
>   auto-inc counter will increment even if the ON DUPLICATE KEY fires

Comment: @robert - if you have a unique key on that table, and you try to insert with ...ON DUPLICATE... and the same unique key, it must not increment, if it does, either we misunderstood each other, or your MySQL has a bug?

Comment: nope. it does increment.   if the following statement has a duplicate ----- INSERT INTO tags (tag_text) VALUES (cur_string) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag_text=cur_string  ----------- then the next actual insert that's not a duplicate will have id like described in the problem. I think it's more like a feature on mysql part rather than a bug. a bit wierd one though

Comment: @robert - Interesting, I am using this a lot, what version of MySQL (if you can, exact one) are you using?

Comment: mysql 5.1.49 and the table is innodb.  You might be using mysql 4.1 which i think is the version where the non increasing auto increment is actually considered a bug. O.o

Comment: no, I am a flavor of 5.1, I'll check it again, might be I am wrong.

Comment: I am having the same problems. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28781 seems to be still active.

Comment: Whether the increment occurs or not depends on the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` setting. If set to a non-zero value, the auto-inc counter will increment even if the ON DUPLICATE KEY fires.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer was useful, however I ran into a problem while using it that basically if your table had no entries it would not work as the select was using the given table, so instead I came up with the following, which will insert even if the table is blank, it also only needs you to insert the table in 2 places and the inserting variables in 1 place, less to get wrong.

```
INSERT INTO database_name.table_name (a,b,c,d)
SELECT 
    i.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        $a AS a, 
            $b AS b,
            $c AS c,
            $d AS d
            /*variables (properly escaped) to insert*/
    ) i
        LEFT JOIN        
    database_name.table_name o ON i.a = o.a AND i.b = o.b /*condition to not insert for*/
WHERE
    o.a IS NULL
LIMIT 1 /*Not needed as can only ever be one, just being sure*/
```

Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but didn't want to use innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0 since it felt like I was killing a fly with a howitzer.

To resolve this problem I ended up using a temporary table.

```
create temporary table mytable_temp like mytable;
```

Then I inserted the values with:

```
insert into mytable_temp values (null,'valA'),(null,'valB'),(null,'valC');
```

After that you simply do another insert but use "not in" to ignore duplicates.

```
insert into mytable (myRow) select mytable_temp.myRow from mytable_temp 
where mytable_temp.myRow not in (select myRow from mytable);
```

I haven't tested this for performance, but it does the job and is easy to read. Granted this was only important because I was working with data that was constantly being updated so I couldn't ignore the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

modified the answer from mu is too short, (simply remove one line)
as i am newbie and i cannot make comment below his answer. Just post it here

the query below works for the first tag

```
 INSERT INTO tablename (tag)
 SELECT $tag
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT tag
    FROM tablename
    WHERE tag = $tag
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just put an extra statement after the insert/update query:
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
And then he automatically picks up the highest prim key id plus 1.