# Avoiding MySQL/InnoDB autoincrement jump with multiple fields being added during insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert, innodb

Reference: [prevent autoincrement on MYSQL duplicate insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924762/prevent-autoincrement-on-mysql-duplicate-insert)

I'm using InnoDB and an INSERT IGNORE statement that causes jumps in the autoincremented ID.

Works for an entry of a single field in the table as they have in that question. However, I'm having the same issue - large jumps in autoincremented ID based on INSERT IGNORE. At this point I have approx 2E4 entries with an ID at nearly 9E6.

However, my INSERT statement has 5 fields I'd like to add. Ultimately, I could do use the statement at the referenced answer to add the unique field. Then use an UPDATE statement to fill in the other fields. But if I wanted 2 separate MySQL statements run I'd just use a SELECT to find out if the unique field was already in the DB then run the INSERT if it wasn't.

Is there any way to INSERT multiple fields while preventing the ID jump that INSERT IGNORE causes? (I use PDO in PHP to interface with my DBs so the INSERT statement is like this: `INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` where `field1` is the unique column.)

Note that I've tried the following:
`INSERT INTO tablename (field1=$field1, field2=$field2, ..., field5=$field5) 
SELECT $field1
FROM tablename WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT field1
   FROM tablename 
   WHERE field1 = $field1
)
LIMIT 1`

and

`INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2, ..., field5) VALUES (?, ?, ..., ?)
SELECT $field1
FROM tablename WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT field1
   FROM tablename 
   WHERE field1 = $field1
)
LIMIT 1`
with `$data = array($field1, $field2, ..., $field5);`

and

`INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2, ..., field5) VALUES (?, ?, ..., ?)
SELECT $field1
FROM tablename WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT field1
   FROM tablename 
   WHERE field1 = ?
)
LIMIT 1`
In this case I have to add `$field1` to the end of the `$data` array given above.

Thanks