# generation of next id in innodb table

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb, insert-update

I have an InndoDB table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `network_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `network_id` (`network_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

In php I receive (it does not matter where from) an array `$network_info`, which contains pairs `network_id`,`nickname`. For those `network_id` which are present in `users` I would like to update their `nickname`. For those, which are not present I would like to insert them into table with generated (new incremented) `id`.

Earlier, I have used `id` as AUTO_INCREMENT, but queries such as `INSERT IGNORE` and so on, increment it all time, even when insertion was not done,and it is not good.

Which is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't think that `INSERT IGNORE` would increment the auto_increment ID, but even if it does that shouldn't matter since that value should be totally transparent

Comment: See, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924762/prevent-autoincrement-on-mysql-duplicate-insert. There will be a lot of attempts. It is not good.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the actual value of the auto_increment ID should not matter

Answer (score 0):

Change your `id` line to this --

```
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

You could stay with int(10), but I always find it best to make it possible for id's to grow to huge sizes just in case someday it's needed.

And after `CHARSET=ut8`, add --

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

That way the table knows where to start incrementing from.

Comment: How to do it without auto_increment? It will be increased all time even when the attempts to insert will be failed. It will be jump out some time.