# mysql - INSERT SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS on empty table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I have the following example query

```
INSERT INTO company (name)
SELECT 'test'
FROM company
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'test' FROM company WHERE name = 'test');
```

However this does not work when the table is empty.

I thought something like this would work

```
INSERT INTO company (name)
SELECT 'test'
FROM company
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company) = 0
  OR
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'test' FROM company WHERE name = 'test');
```

But it didn't work either. Any ideas?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5747f0/1

Comment: Please update your question and describe what you actually want to happen here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure how to describe it any clearer. It should insert  if the name doesn't exist already (which already works once the table is filled) or if the table is empty (current query does not work if table is empty). So the only bug is fixing it when the table is empty.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your example ([see here](http://rextester.com/SJN88611)).  Maybe you should give a reproducible example.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated with fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at the following query:

```
INSERT INTO company (name)
SELECT 'test'
FROM company
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'test' FROM company WHERE name = 'test');
```

Since the `company` table is currently empty, *no records will ever be returned* from this query, regardless of the `WHERE EXISTS` logic, which by the way is completely correct.  If you instead use the `dual` table you will see the query working:

```
INSERT INTO company (name)
SELECT 'test'
FROM dual
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'test' FROM company WHERE name = 'test');
```

Comment: What does `'test'` represent? I _think_ I need the same query for my solution but not clear with just a query for an answer without an explanation behind it.

Answer (score 1):

No suprise that this has come up before [prevent autoincrement on MYSQL duplicate insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924762/prevent-autoincrement-on-mysql-duplicate-insert)

I like this solution

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (NAME) SELECT 'TEST' AS INNAME FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NAME FROM COMPANY
    WHERE NAME = 'TEST'
    LIMIT 1
);

MariaDB [sandbox]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COMPANY;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TABLE COMPANY (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(10), UNIQUE (NAME));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO COMPANY (NAME) VALUES ('TEST');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO COMPANY (NAME) SELECT 'TEST' AS INNAME FROM DUAL
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    ->     SELECT NAME FROM COMPANY
    ->     WHERE NAME = 'TEST'
    ->     LIMIT 1
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO COMPANY (NAME) SELECT 'ABC' AS INNAME FROM DUAL
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    ->     SELECT NAME FROM COMPANY
    ->     WHERE NAME = 'ABC'
    ->     LIMIT 1
    -> );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM COMPANY;
+----+------+
| ID | NAME |
+----+------+
|  2 | ABC  |
|  1 | TEST |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reinventing the wheel here. A much simpler approach would be to define `name` as a unique key (or primary key) and then use the `insert ignore` syntax:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO company(name) VALUES ('test')
```

Comment: Reason why I don't want to `INSERT IGNORE` is because I don't want the id to keep incrementing every time someone tries to insert the same name.

Comment: Then your current query would fail to do that...the insert would be blocked and nothing would increment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not sure what you mean, but when I run the original query (and there's already something in the database) the id will not increment if the same name is in there already