# Too many auto increments with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, on-duplicate-key

I have a basic table with columns:

- id (primary with AI)
- name (unique)
- etc

If the unique column doesn't exist, INSERT the row, otherwise UPDATE the row....

```
INSERT INTO pages (name, etc)
VALUES
  'bob',
  'randomness'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 name = VALUES(name),
 etc = VALUES(etc)
```

The problem is that if it performs an UPDATE, the auto_increment value on the id column goes up. So if a whole bunch of UPDATES are performed, the id auto_increment goes through the roof.

Apparently it was a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28781

...but I'm using InnoDB on mySQL 5.5.8 on shared hosting.

Other people having issues with no solution years ago:
[prevent autoincrement on MYSQL duplicate insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924762/prevent-autoincrement-on-mysql-duplicate-insert) and 
[Why does MySQL autoincrement increase on failed inserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787910/why-does-mysql-autoincrement-increase-on-failed-inserts)

Ideas on a fix? Have I maybe structured the database incorrectly somehow?

******EDIT****: It appears adding innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0 to your my.ini file fixes the problem but what options do I have for shared hosting?

******EDIT 2******: OK, I think my only option is to change to MyISAM as the storage engine. Being a mega mySQL newbie, I hope that doesn't cause many issues. Yeah?

Comment: One big problem with MyISAM is that it doesn't support the definition of database relations. InnoDB does support that.

Comment: innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0 worked for me. thanks

Comment: I switched to Aria (MyISAM in MariaDB) which prevents the auto_increment

Comment: `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` is slow down concurente `INSERT` because use table-lock for auto-inc field. This is can be bad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to bypass this behaviour of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICTE KEY UPDATE`.

You can however put two statements, one `UPDATE` and one `INSERT`, in one [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html):

```
START TRANSACTION ;

UPDATE pages
SET etc = 'randomness'
WHERE name = 'bob' ;

INSERT INTO pages (name, etc)
SELECT 
      'bob' AS name
    , 'randomness' AS etc 
FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM pages p
        WHERE p.name = 'bob'
      ) ;

COMMIT ;
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I ended up going this route. That auto increment issue is a pain in the arse. Didn't need the "AS name" and "AS etc" parts.

Comment: No, those aliases are not needed, indeed.

Comment: @NathanWaters: Added a link to MySQL's documentation about transactions.

Comment: Could you also do this? `INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (name, etc)
SELECT 
      'bob' AS name
    , 'randomness' AS etc 
FROM dual `

Comment: @TimoHuovinen `INSERT IGNORE` burns an ID in the same way as `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: @tepples yes. Plus, and depending on settings, it will also ignore other errors. Which is usually not good.

Answer (score -4):

The on duplicate key functionality of MySQL is exactly the same as doing two separate queries, one to select, then one to either update the selected record, or insert a new record. Doing so programmatically is just as fast and will prevent this problem in the future as well as make your code more portable.

Comment: it's not nearly just as fast according to what I am seeing