# Error unique index mysql

Tags: mysql, field, unique

I have an unique index in field mysql. My table is the follow:

```
Id INT(11)(AUTOINCREMENT)
login (VARCHAR) (UNIQUE)
```

If I do :

```
INSERT (login) VALUES ('test');//ok, the Id field equal 1
INSERT (login) VALUES ('test');//error, login field is unique
INSERT (login) VALUES ('test1');//ok, but Id field is 3
```

Why it jump the Id 2??

Comment: this is a repeated question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787910/why-does-mysql-autoincrement-increase-on-failed-inserts, you'll probably find your answer there.