# Avoiding failed inserts to avoid spurious autoincrement

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, auto-increment

My problem is the same as [Why does MySQL autoincrement increase on failed inserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2787910/), but instead of increasing my `id` field, I would prefer just to rewrite the `INSERT` query that is causing me trouble. Pretend I have a database with two fields, `id` and `username`, where `id` is a primary key and `username` is a unique key. I'm essentially looking for syntax that would do `INSERT...IF NOT EXISTS`. Right now, I do

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`username`) 
    VALUES ('foo') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id`=`id`
```

I only have one thread writing to the database, so I don't need any sort of concurrency protection. Suggestions?

Comment: why is it such a problem having the auto-increment field updating ?

Comment: Because I want to avoid having to use a `HUGEINT` for the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this:

```
INSERT INTO tableX (username) 
  SELECT 'foo' AS username
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM tableX 
          WHERE username = 'foo'
        ) ;
```

If you want to include values for more columns:

```
INSERT INTO tableX (username, dateColumn) 
  SELECT 'foo'                       --- the aliases are not needed             
       , NOW()                       --- actually
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM tableX 
          WHERE username = 'foo'
        ) ;
```

Comment: What's `FROM dual`?  **EDIT** Ignore me.  Found it in the manual.  Great answer +1

Comment: `dual` is a dummy table with one row exactly (originally in Oracle DBMS, where it had 2 rows, thus the name). It can be used to construct a 1-row table.

Comment: Why does this work when the manual says "*you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery*"?  Is it because one only inserts if nothing was selected?  Or does `EXISTS` avoid actually selecting anything?

Comment: @eggyal: Where does it say that? (Avctually I'm selecting from 'dual' here, not from the same table but that's anotehr issue).

Comment: Third bullet - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html; won't the `EXISTS` subquery lock the table and prevent a write?

Comment: No it works fine. Maybe the docs are wrong or are refering to previous versions, I don't know.

Comment: @ypercube How does this work if you want to insert multiple columns? On my real table, I have a `DATETIME` column that I want to fill with `NOW()`, but doing an `INSERT INTO...VALUES` with your select statement as one of the args isn't working.

Comment: I haven't `VALUES` into my example.

Comment: @eggyal: What is not allowed is this kind of subqueries (inside `VALUES`): `INSERT INTO tableX VALUES( 1, 2, (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tableX) )`

Comment: I have used the same table in `FROM` clause in much more complex statements, like: `INSERT INTO t SELECT a.id * m + b.id + m FROM t AS a JOIN t AS b ON b.id <= a.id CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS m FROM t) AS maxt`

Comment: @Andy: see my edit. You can't mix `INSERT ... VALUES` with `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax. Use either one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can prevent the counter from being incremented, for the reasons given in the answers the question to which you've linked.

You have three options:

1. Live with skipped identifiers; do you really expect to use up 64-bits?
2. Check for existence of the existing record prior to attempting the `INSERT`:

   ```
   DELIMITER ;;

   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE username = 'foo') THEN
     INSERT INTO `table` (username) VALUES ('foo');
   END IF;;

   DELIMITER ;
   ```

   Or, better yet, use the `FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` form suggested by @ypercube.
3. Reset the counter after each insert.  If performing the `INSERT` operation within a stored procedure, you could do this using a handler for duplicate key errors:

   ```
   DELIMITER ;;

   CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(IN uname CHAR(16) CHARSET latin1) BEGIN
     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' BEGIN
       -- WARNING: THIS IS NOT SAFE FOR CONCURRENT CONNECTIONS
       SET @qry = CONCAT(
         'ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = ',
         (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table`)
       );
       PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
       EXECUTE stmt;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
       SET @qry = NULL;
     END;
     INSERT INTO `table` (username) VALUES (uname);
   END;;
   DELIMITER ;
   ```

   Bearing in mind the (valid) concerns @ypercube raised in his comments beneath regarding this strategy, you might instead use:

   ```
   SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT - 1
   FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE  table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name = 'table';
   ```

Comment: No to 4, never use option 4. It's not safe.

Comment: I tried adding your "ALTER TABLE" in a stored procedure, but MySQL yelled at me. What's wrong here?

`CREATE DEFINER=\`me\`@\`localhost\` 
PROCEDURE \`TEST\`(IN \`uname\` CHAR(16) CHARSET latin1) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
INSERT INTO \`test\` ( \`username\` ) VALUES ( uname ) ON DUPLICATE KEY (ALTER TABLE \`table\` AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM \`table\`));`

Comment: @ypercube: Why is it not safe, given the OP stated he has "*only one thread writing to the database, so I don't need any sort of concurrency protection*"?

Comment: @AndyShulman: You can only `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE ...`; trying to `ALTER TABLE` in that fashion is a syntax error.  You must use separate statements as shown.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your comment about "handler for duplicate key errors", then. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @eggyal: Because he may need it in the future. Will he (or the guy responsible in 5 years) remember to change this code?

Comment: And even more crucial, what happens if some records have been previously deleted? Then the `MAX(id)` will be smaller than some `id` which has been already used (and deleted). This may be fine but it may not be (if you had referencing rows in other tables that were left orphaned). In any case, re-using an `id` is not best practice.

Comment: @ypercube That's why foreign key constraints are fantastic.

Comment: @ypercube: Agree with your first concern re future requirements/understanding; to allay the second, the approach in my updated answer (obtaining the discarded value by proxy through the information schema) should suffice?  Besides which, restarting the server would resort to `MAX(id)` and cause those same concerns anyway...

Comment: @eggyal Could you check that? That fails with a syntax error, for me.

Comment: @AndyShulman: I think you will have to go via a variable; see my updated answer.

Comment: @eggyal Now it's `near 'id; END; INSERT INTO \`test_table\` (\`username\`) VALUES ( uname ); END' at line 7`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11275/discussion-between-eggyal-and-andy-shulman)

Answer (score 2):

you can simply reset the auto increment field after the failed insert

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT =1;

this will not reset the auto increment to 1 but will reset it to the current maximum plus one

also note that the user you are connected with to the DB should has alter privilege to the targeted table

Answer (score 0):

You can also check before insert that user if it was inserted before, it will cost an extra call into your DB but, if the user already exists, you can return the information that you found and a fake insert is avoided.

Answer (score -1):

use `INSERT IGNORE INTO table`. Check the below post

http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html

You can do it like:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`username`) 
VALUES ('foo')      
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `username`= 'foo'
```

OR

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table`
SET `username` = 'foo'
```

Comment: No. This still autoincrements `id`, even when no row is inserted.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. If a duplicate key exist then it will skip it; if not then a new row will be inserted and obhiously id will be incremented. are you looking for a different behavior?

Comment: It does. I tested it. I ran `INSERT IGNORE INTO \`test\`(\`username\`) VALUES ('testuser')` 5 times, and then checked what the next auto-increment value was.

Comment: You mean, even though it ignores and doesn't insert but still id gets autoincremented? that's strange ... haven't tested though. Would suggest you to post the same question in mysql forum as well.

Comment: Yup. Inserted with `id` of 1, but on successful insert of a different username the next `id` is 6.