# Mysql auto-increment skipping id

Tags: mysql, database, skip

I have a problem hope anyone here will help me!

auto-increment skipping values on my website (table user).

For Example: **id: 30,31,32,33,35**

As you can see, auto-increment skip id 34.

My question! is there an way to repair database, in other words, to repair all id from database in order to add id 34.

Comment: Nothing to stop you from manually inserting a row with ID 34 ...

Comment: This is often caused by a failed insert or deleted record. Just insert with an id of 34

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key

Comment: you can manually add it by insert query passing your desired id value.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. No, you should not care about what are id actual values, if you designed your application correctly.

Comment: There is nothing to "repair" because nothing is broken.

Comment: Don't worry about the missing ids.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does MySQL autoincrement increase on failed inserts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787910/why-does-mysql-autoincrement-increase-on-failed-inserts)